# Pass multiple objects to jinja using Flask

Tags: flask, jinja2

How to pass multiple objects to jinja template using flask:

```
....
t = t.split(', ')
for i in t:
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=i).all()
return render_template('example.html', user=user)
```

Here renders only one user with last value of 't' list, how to render multiple users based on all values of list 't'?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a bad way to query. Making individual querys so many times is bad.
instead us the `in_` function. making

```
t = t.split(', ')
users = []
for i in t:
    users.append(User.query.filter_by(username=i).all())
```

into

`User.query.filter(User.username.in_(t)).all()`

That returns all the users that have the usernames in the `t` list

Comment: If you have'nt changed it, you should, the other way is really ineffective

Comment: You're right, 'for' cycle for plenty queries is not good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a list...

```
....
t = t.split(', ')
users = []
for i in t:
    users.append(User.query.filter_by(username=i).all())
return render_template('example.html', users=users)
```